# Gitlab shell executor shutting down my machine

Tags: gitlab, devops, ubuntu-18.04, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab pipeline which executes it's jobs in my local machine, which has ubuntu 18.04 OS, using shell executor once the pipeline is triggered. It used to work fine with my ubuntu 20.04; once I downgraded my OS, my laptop is shutting down or turning into a black screen whenever the jobs  are being executed.I have shared the final log messages from gitlab server! [image]

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to check `/var/log/syslog` to see if or what errors are being thrown by your Runner. GitLab Runner logs to `/var/log/syslog` by default: [GitLab Runner troubleshooting tips](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/faq/)

Additionally, I'd check to see if there are any kernel failures at `/var/log/kern.log` (for whatever reason) considering you're having overall hardware issues when using a shell executor. That's definitely an odd issue.

Comment: This seems like good advice, but I do not think it is an answer by Stack Overflow standards.

Comment: Fair enough! I'm new to StackOverflow, so learning as I go. Appreciate your feedback.